# How does this Twitter API result become automatically HTML formatted?

Tags: html, xml, json, api, twitter

I know that [Twitter is API-centric](http://engineering.twitter.com/2010/09/tech-behind-new-twittercom.html), meaning that it, like all Twitter apps, retrieves its data via the API.

When I access https://api.twitter.com/1/legal/tos.json (or [.xml](https://api.twitter.com/1/legal/tos.xml) if you prefer) I am given a `JSON` formatted result that only seems to contain plaintext and no additional formatting.  That being said, if we assume that https://twitter.com/tos retrieves it's data from the same resource, how does it become formatted with **hyperlinks**, **headings**, **etc.**?

I've noticed that there are line breaks `\n` which break the `JSON` response into multiple segments. Is there some post-processing of this data to replace certain numbers of line breaks with specific HTML tags?

For example:

```
\n\n\n  =>  <h3>
\n\n    =>  <p>
Tip     =>  <p class="tip>
```

However, the above formatting rules would not account for the hyperlinks strewn throughout the page.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that there's a master copy of the text formatted as HTML. The formatted page has access to the HTML version of the text through either a private API or a different request to the public API.

Separately, the JSON and XML versions are generated by a backend service which has access to the HTML-formatted text and converts it to JSON or XML or whatever else Twitter wants it to.

I think it's extremely unlikely that twitter is using either the JSON or XML versions of the text you linked to to build their pages.

Answer (score -1):

You just answered your own question.

The idea they use a preset format \n and other keywords like tip.

```
\n\n for <p> 
\n\nTip for <p class="tip">
\n\nSecret would technically be for <p class="Secret">

\" for start of bold
```

When they retrieve the data from the API, they replace \n s by the html they want to present it with

Comment: This doesn't seem possible because it doesn't explain the hyperlinks.  I'll update question to reflect this point.

Comment: My guess would be they have something to process it ... the above explains all the formatting save the hyper links....
u can see that with the way have highlighted \n s here
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/legal/tos

Comment: Note that some of the hyper links are strewn around in the json... however the others arent, my guess would be a simple find substring and surround with hyoerlink....

Again this is presuming they are using the Same API we are referring to for the TOS page

Comment: Since Twitter has control over their own data, there'd be no reason to write such an intricate, fragile text processing function when they could just format their data correctly to begin with. It's easier to remove formatting than to add it, so I think the JSON & XML versions are downconverted from HTML rather than the other way around.

Comment: i agree with @ChadvonNau but servAce85 has posted a link which says that twitter.com is developed of their own API ... hence my speculation!!!!